# mongo shell script won't let me include "use <database>"

Tags: shell, mongodb, scripting

32-bit mongo 2.0.1 on a windows XP machine

```
//script filename: test.js  (one line shell script file to store a person)
db.cTest.save({Name: "Fred", Age:21});
```

run against database dbTest by entering the following 2 shell commands:

```
    > use dbTest
    switched to dbTest
    > load("test.js")
```

So far, so good.

But if I try and include the "use" statement in the script it fails:

```
//script filename: test.js  (including "use" statement)
use dbTest;
db.cTest.save({Name: "Fred", Age:21});
```

fails with error msg as follows:

```
    > load("test.js")
    SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
    Mon Dec 19 11:56:31: Error: error loading js file temp.js (shell):1
```

Adding or removing semicolons to test.js doesn't seem to matter.

So how do you put a "use" directive into a mongo shell script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell

> **use dbname**
> This command does not work in scripted mode. Instead you will need to explicitly define the  database in the connection (/dbname in the example above).
>
> Alternately, you can also create a connection within the script:
>
> db2 = connect("server:27017/otherdbname")

Comment: The answer below is the correct one. For an overview of the difference between interactive and scripted JS: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo

Comment: use db_name;  used to work, now in newer versions we have to connect with db name as mentioned above.

Answer (score 67):

In a mongo script you can use the `db.getSiblingDB('new_db_name')` to get a reference of a new database. So, it it not mandatory to give the database name in the command line. You can use the `script.js`:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('new_db_name');
print(db);

// the rest of your code for database "new_db_name"
```

and the output of this script is (invoked with `mongo script.js`):

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: test
sag
```

Comment: This is perfect for when you want to write a quick script or function from within the mongo shell.  The key line to switch databases is db = db.getSiblingDB('new_db_name');

Comment: The docs can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo)

Answer (score 16):

Well, it still is unfortunate that "load('file.js')" and "mongo file.js" don't actually use the same script interpreter as the interactive mongo shell. Opening the connection explicitly in the script is potentially a violation of the DRY principle because mongo already knows that information. What does work, though, is piping the file into mongo rather than passing its name on the command line:

```
mongo <file.js
```

Comment: The '<' operator is reserved for future use.