# how should I use "use" in a JS script within Mongo to use a db?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to check if a user exists and if it doesn't I create it for a specific db. First I login directly to the admin db and then I try to switch to "univa" db, and this is were my script fail

```
if(db.system.users.find({user:'pedro'}).count() === 0){ 
    use univa; // this fail
    db.createUser({user:'pedro', pwd:'123', roles:[{role: 'readWrite', db: 'univa'}, 'readWrite','dbOwner']});
}
```

how Can I switch to a different db within a JS script?

Comment: What Mongo driver are you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565376/mongo-shell-script-wont-let-me-include-use-database